# What are differences between Red5 and Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, amazon-ec2, red5, flash-media-server

I'm building a simple flash app that records user voice. I'm new to flash.

What should I consider when choosing between red5 and flash media server?

Can they both be hosted on EC2?

Answer (score 5):

The first, and perhaps major, difference is cost. You can install both to a Linux machine, and I assume that EC2 is capable of hosting both (but don't know this for sure). However, you have to pay for each instance of FMS, probably making it the wrong option for EC2 with instances going up and down whenever you want.
Red5 doesn't seem totally compatible with FMS. For instance, right now I evaluating both and the same video player that runs smoothly with FMS will not allow me to control teh seek bar if the video is served from red5. However, I expect this can be solved.
FMS does have extra functions for SWV security (verification) that could be useful too.
If I was you, I would try doing it with Red5 first, and switch to FMS if you can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that documentation of Red5 is rare... and can be frustrating to setup without prior knowledge

Answer (score 1):

red5 is free (open source) and server side is on java and you can do a lot of stuff with java,
FMS is is not free and server side is on Action Script 1

Answer (score 1):

Not just java , you can write serverside in Jython (python on java jvm) , jruby ( ruby on java) , Rhino JS (Java Script) and Groovy.